# Pointing to deeply nested objects parsed by a body parser(express)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am an api developer, and the project I am working on right now supports XML and JSON communication. I often have to switch between the two, and XML is often deeply nested and sometimes clients will send us incorrect data that does not satisfy our contract. There is schema validation in place but sometimes messages will get through none the less and if a field is not present it will throw a null exception.

Something like:

```
foo.foo2[0].foo3[0].anotherfoo[0].thisAnotherFoo[0]
```

I have tried nesting `hasOwnProperty('foo')` for every node I was accessing but I have never seen anything like this before and there has got to be a better way. I know jQuery doesn't bomb out if you try to access a property in the DOM that is not there but is there a Node equivalent?

Comment: What's the desired behavior for missing paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive function that traverses the given path and bails (but doesn't throw) if it encounters a nonexistent node.

```js
const data = {
  foo: {
    foo2: [{
      foo3: [{
          anotherfoo: [{
            thisAnotherFoo: [{
              hello: "hi"
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};

// regex to split the next path chunk from the remaining path
// e.g. 'foo[0].foo2[0].foo3[0]' => ['foo[0]', 'foo2[0].foo3[0]']
const chunk = /([^\.]+)(?:\.(.*))*/;

// regex to test for array access
// e.g. foo[0] => ['foo', '0']
const arrayAccess = /(\w+)(?:\[(\d+)\])*/;

// recursively traverses the given path on data,
// bailing if it encounters a missing path segment
function queryPath(data, path) {

  // consume the current element from path (e.g. 'foo[0]')
  // and capture the remaining path
  const [, current, remaining] = chunk.exec(path);

  // if this path segment uses array access notation,
  // separate the index from the name
  const [, name, index] = arrayAccess.exec(current);

  // get the current node by name (e.g. 'foo')
  const node = data[name];

  // if there's no such node, bail.
  if (node == null) {
    return node;
  }

  // resolve array access if present
  const value = index ? node[parseInt(index)] : node;

  // exit if there's no value here or if
  // we've reached the end of the path
  if (value == null || !remaining) {
    return value;
  }

  // continue with remaining data and path
  return queryPath(value, remaining);
}

// returns {hello: 'hi'}
console.log(queryPath(data, 'foo.foo2[0].foo3[0].anotherfoo[0].thisAnotherFoo[0]'));

// returns undefined
console.log(queryPath(data, 'foo.foo2[0].NONEXISTENTFOO[0].anotherfoo[0].thisAnotherFoo[0]'));
```

Comment: What does the first comma in this array represent?

const [, current, remaining]

Comment: [`regex.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value) returns the entire matched text, followed by the captured groups. We don't need the first item so we're skipping over it to get the second and third. It's the equivalent of `const [entireMatch, current, remaining] = chunk.exec(path)`, but without declaring `entireMatch`.